# Global class members only instanciated once in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code,

```
class A:
  pass

class B:
  member = A()

  def hello(self):
    print(repr( type(self).member ))

b1 = B()
b2 = B()

b1.hello()
b2.hello()
```

gives the following output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x0000025193C03DA0>
<__main__.A object at 0x0000025193C03DA0>
```

It seems that python only instantiate A once and uses its value for all the instances of B. Why does it happen and is there a way of instantiating different global members for all instances of B ?

Comment: use `__init__` to initialize `A` for each instance of `B`.

Comment: can I still reference it as `type(self).member` after that ?

Comment: No. Why would you want to do that? And how would it be "global" if it's different for every member?